# Visual Studio Makefile Project makes extraneous 'obj' folder

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, visual-studio-2012

I'm using a Makefile project in Visual Studio 2012 express just fine. However, regardless of the Build Command specified, Visual Studio always makes an 'obj' folder containing empty subfolders obj\Win32\Debug and obj\Win32\Release.

To reproduce the problem, simply create a "Visual C++ - General - Makefile Project" and use a DOS command like 'dir' in the Build Command Line. As soon as you build, the empty obj\Win32\Debug folder will show up.

I can simply skip these in my Mercurial ignore file but it'd be nice to find a fix. Anyone know how to make Visual Studio not generate these empty folders?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620224/move-obj-folder-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 2):

Found a trick: to set the intermediate output directory on an existing directory. I modified the project file by hand and added this:

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>$(ProjectDir)</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

inside the configuration PropertyGroup. I used the project directory, which obviously already exists. No more useless obj directory!

Answer (score 1):

The **obj** folder represents VS' own metadata about your project for intellisense support and designer support (for WF/WPF apps). For the most part you can ignore the folder completely without issue.

On occasion though this data can become corrupt and cause VS to show invalid Intellisense options and the workflow/WPF designer can cause errors. Closing VS and deleting the **obj** folder will quickly resolve this though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in this case of a Makefile project that uses an external build tool, this obj folder is always empty.

Is there a way to perhaps redirect it to the intermediate directory? $(IntDir).

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is no way to control this behavior in VS. It occurs in practically every project type too, so its not limited to VC++ apps.

Comment: Thought of a different approach you can take to have your build work in a totally clean directory. By default builds will go to either bin/$(configuration) but you can direct this to be anywhere. Maybe having the outputs directed somewhere outside your project space would be a decent approach?