# Move obj folder in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Because the path becomes too long (more than 260 characters), I need to create the `obj` folder elsewhere.

How can I tell Visual Studio 2012 to create this folder in a specified path?

Comment: I don't think you can do this; you can however shorten the path to your project/solution and/or the assembly name.  If you are very deeply rooted folder wise, perhaps consider the use a of symlink or directory junction off to shorten the path.

Comment: That's an accident waiting to happen. Currently the obj folder is affected... what else might be affected? Why not reduce risk and move everything to somewhere closer to the root?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-a-drive-letter-to-a-folder-the-easy-way-in-windows/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot move the project belongs to a workspace that must be named in this way

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How can I redirect the "bin" and "obj" directories to a different location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735534/how-can-i-redirect-the-bin-and-obj-directories-to-a-different-location)*

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You'll need to edit the project file (XML) to specify the `<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>`. This value defaults to `obj\`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
  ...
  <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>some\path\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Apparently you don't need to put this in a separate/special property group.  The main (first) PropertyGroup at the top of the project file works for me. ;)

Comment: I was killing myself with this.  I was looking into modifying the build instructions.  One liner!  Thanks.

Comment: That sucks. For C/C++ projects (also for C++/CLI) you just change the path for `Intermediate Directory` in `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General`.

Comment: Yes, it works. The folder can even be completely outside the root folder with the .sln folder (thus complete separation between source files and generated files), by using relative paths, e.g. ..\..\build\obj\. This also works for the `bin` folder, by the `OutputPath` property (like `BaseIntermediateOutputPath`) or through the project properties (→ "Build" → "Configuration" = "Debug", "Output" → "Output path" = ` ..\..\build\bin\Debug\ ` ). Note that, in contrast, to obj, the path must be unique, one for each configuration / platform combination (e.g. 4 for debug/release, 32 bit/64 bit).

Comment: See also *[How can I redirect the “bin” and “obj” directories to a different location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735534)*

Answer (score 4):

...And (in addition to ***Sam Harwell***) You can use constants and can change any particular `<PropertyGroup/>` (only "release" for example) this way:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  .....
  <OutputPath>\your_projects\bin\$(SolutionName)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>\your_projects\obj\$(SolutionName)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```