# How to prevent Visual Studio 2012 from creating "obj" and "Debug" folders in the source tree

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, makefile

I have a C++ Makefile project in Visual Studio. The source tree has three folders:

1. bin
2. src
3. include

But, when I build the project, VS12 creates two additional folders:

1. obj
2. Debug

How can I  prevent Visual Studio from doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620224/move-obj-folder-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a trick: to set the intermediate output directory to an existing directory. I modified the project file by hand and added this:

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>$(ProjectDir)</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

inside the configuration PropertyGroup. I used the project directory, which obviously already exists. No more useless `obj` directory!

Answer (score 1):

Solution for VS 2019 (folders **obj** and **bin** are not created):

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>nul</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(ProjectDir)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```