# Change the location of obj/Xcode folder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Is it possible to explicitly set some custom location of obj/Xcode folder? I need this to improve the performance when using Visual Studio plugin.  I accept hackish variants too ))

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here (though not for Xcode folder specifically, but rather for obj folder in general) https://stackoverflow.com/a/15620341/3507404

UPDATE:
It seems that Xamarin does not respect that property and still sets Xcode folder to default location.